# .htaccess rewrite remove directory name from request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a redirect from a request like [http://test.site.com/**pagename--city**/] to something like [http://test.site.com/**state/pagename--city**/] and then back to [http://test.site.com/pagename--city/]. The 'state/pagename--city' are physical directories on the server. So if someone clicks on [http://test.site.com/pagename--city/] I need to execute [http://test.site.com/state/pagename--city/index.php] but the URL to remain [http://test.site.com/pagename--city/]. Any help appreciated. Thnx.

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)--(.*)/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/state/
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/state%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule .* page.php?&[|]v1||%{REQUEST_URI}[|]v2||-[|]v3||%{HTTP_HOST}[|]v4||%{REQUEST_FILENAME}[|]v5||EOL[~|~]= [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)--(.*)$ /state/$1--$2/index.php&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear, is this what you are looking for?

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)--(.+)$    /state/$1--$2/index.php
```

Comment: Not quite I will try to give more details. For example I have a link on my site like this [http://test.site.com/pagename--city/] but on the server I have a physical directory structure like this /state/pagename--city. When you click on [http://test.site.com/pagename--city/] I want to request [http://test.site.com/state/pagename--city/index.php] but the URL to remain like this [http://test.site.com/pagename--city/]

Comment: Then what I have given should do exactly the same :)

Comment: Sorry not working :| I get a 500 error. Here is my .htaccess file    `Options +FollowSymlinks  

RewriteEngine On  

RewriteBase /  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)--(.*)/?$  
RewriteRule ^(.+)--(.+)$    /state/$1--$2/index.php [L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  


RewriteRule .* page.php?&[|]v1||%{REQUEST_URI}[|]v2||-[|]v3||%  {HTTP_HOST}[|]v4||%{REQUEST_FILENAME}[|]v5||EOL[~|~]= [QSA,L]  `

Comment: Try once by removing the RewriteCond. I feel it's not letting your RewriteRule get executed.

Comment: Still getting the error. I tried this  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)--(.*)/?$  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/state/  RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/state%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` and this redirects me to [/state/pagename--city/index.php] but i don't know how to remove 'state' from URL

Comment: Can you post the full .htaccess in code mode as part of your question? The formatting is making it hard to understand.